# labels to the axis - conver int (second) to hours

Tags: time, format, gnuplot, axis, axis-labels

How can I make axis labels in the HOURS: MINUTES format (10:00 for example), if the data on the axis are represented as integers in the range [0...N]?

For example:

```
range [0..43200]
axis labels: 00:00 04:00 08:00 12:00
```

seconf example:

```
range [28800..172800]
axis labels: 08:00 16:00 24:00 08:00 16:00 24:00
```

When I use code:

```
set xdata time
set format x "%H:%M"
```

it does not work correctly  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want that the time does not wrap at 24:00? i.e. 32:00 40:00 48:00 instead of 08:00 16:00 24:00 ?
See `help time_specifiers`

Simple test code:

```
reset session

set xdata time
set format x "%tH:%tM"
set xrange [0:180000]

plot x
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: warning on line `set xdata time` :( `line 83: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points`

Comment: this code has not 83 lines. So, it must be something else with your code around... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This option worked!

```
set xtics format "%tH:%tM" time
```

Unfortunately, it gives for the range [0: 172800] the values `0:00 - 48:00`, and I would like `0:00-23:00-0:00-23:00`